# How to use empty titles for buttons on the ApplicationBar?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

One of my buttons' icon is a trash can, which should be only titled with "delete" according to WP7's rule, but in fact it's not a "delete" button, and we don't want to change its icon, either. So the only solution seems to be giving it an empty title, which is confirmed to be acceptable by MS. but if I set its `Text` to empty string, or just leave it as unset, I got an error like "cannot be empty title".

So is there a way to set it empty, or just hide the title from users? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that your application will fail the marketplace test if you have a different text below the trashcan icon. Having no text (which will not build) or trying to hide this text will be a reason to fail the marketplace test.

Personally I need this text in alot of applications to discover what a button actually is doing. My suggestion would be to use a descriptive name for the button and don't worry about the text being the reason to reject your app.

Comment: Can't agree more, I do think a different text should be ok, at least it's better than no text. But actually the suggestion came from Microsoft. By now we're still trying to convince them to accept a different text for the trashcan.

Comment: What is the function of your trashcan button? Maybe we can think of a different icon to use?

Comment: It's a "ban" button, refers to "play this no more". The problem here is that we have already used the trashcan in our service for a long time,  it has become part of the product, changing the icon now is not the best option.